# C# converting to double returns infinity

Tags: c#, double, converters, infinity, typedescriptor

I have a method:

```
public void StoreNumberInSmallestType(ValueType number)
{
    if (numberTypes == null)
        numberTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(sbyte), typeof(short), typeof(int), typeof(long), typeof(float), typeof(double) };

    foreach (Type t in numberTypes)
    {
        try
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);
            value = converter.ConvertTo(number, t);

            Type = value.GetType();

            return;
        }

        catch (OverflowException) { }
    }
}
```

The method is inside a class where the variable `value` is defined as `dynamic`.

When used like this:

```
StoreNumberInSmallestType(Math.Pow(200, 100));
```

`value` ends up being `Infinity`.  If I step through the process, I find that the value of `number` is not `Infinity`, but is the result expressed in scientific notation.  Something bad is happening whenever `number` gets converted and stored inside `value`.  Does anybody know why `number` holds the correct value, but `value` does not?

## EDIT:

Here is a complete code sample:

Main:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            c1.StoreNumberInSmallestType(Math.Pow(200, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        List<Type> numberTypes;
        dynamic value;
        public Type Type { get; set; }

        public void StoreNumberInSmallestType(ValueType number)
        {
            if (numberTypes == null)
                numberTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(sbyte), typeof(short), typeof(int), typeof(long), typeof(float), typeof(double) };

            foreach (Type t in numberTypes)
            {
                try
                {
                    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);
                    value = converter.ConvertTo(number, t);

                    Type = value.GetType();

                    return;
                }

                catch (OverflowException) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You code does not compile, you are missing some essential parts here. Is the code within a generic class?

Comment: sorry bout that, lemme just post an entire example scenario.

Comment: It might be better to, instead of using try-catch, rather test for if a value is larger than the maximum of each type before converting.

Comment: @benjer3 hmm... hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: @benjer3 Is there any way to test the maximum of the types by using the type array I already have or would I end up having to hard code a series of if statements to test each type?

Comment: Looks like, since the compiler doesn't know if a type is numeric, you would have to hard-code it.  Seems as though there would be an interface for numeric types, but I guess not.

Comment: Oh, how about a dictionary of type `Dictionary<Type, double>`.  Each `double` would be the max value of the corresponding type.  You can then foreach over the it and, if `number` is less than the `value` of the `KeyValuePair`, convert it to the type of the `key` and return.

Comment: @benjer3 Wow, nice solution. I had to create some extension methods for the ValueType class to make it easier. I used the code here to do it tho, so pretty simple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get infinity for the double conversion, but for the float conversion.
There you get Infinity and no exception and then your code returns before you get to the double conversion.

Comment: I'm glad this boiled down to operator error. I thought it a bit odd for double to really be System.Single

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you run a conversion on your number with the Single Type which has a max value of `3.40282347E+38` and the value of nunber is `1.2676506002282294E+230` so you are exceeding the [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3www918f) Value Type. Once you make it to the Double Type it will have `1.2676506002282294E+230` in value.

From above link:

> If the magnitude of the result of a floating-point operation is too large for the destination format, the result of the operation is PositiveInfinity or NegativeInfinity, as appropriate for the sign of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow conditions cause Infinity; You can check for this with either of these:

- MSDN: [double.IsPositiveInfinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.ispositiveinfinity)
- MSDN: [double.IsNegativeInfinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnegativeinfinity)

The float conversion is causing you to exceed the limitations of your data type.